# Share image to whatsapp Android 7.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am creating image in my application and allow user to send it directly in whatsapp, facebook, instagram etc. Its not working in Android 7.1.1. Its not generating any error for send it. Share intent is working fine without any issue just not working custom sharing intent with facebook, whatsapp etc. My code is like below. Let me know if someone have any idea that whats wrong in this.

```
private void shareViaInstaApp() {
        try {
            Intent instaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            File imageFile = new File(rootFile.toString());
            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PreviewActivity.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFile);
            instaIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share..");
            instaIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            instaIntent.setType("image/*");
            instaIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
            instaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(instaIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(PreviewActivity.this, "You don't seem to have Instagram installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Debug Not Passing ahead from this line

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFile);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want share in specific app you just use `instaIntent.setPackage("Pacakename")` other wise you have to remove this line..

And

specifically share in **whatsapp** use this way

```
instaIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
```

specifically share in **Messenger** use this way

```
instaIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca")
```